# Golang wiki building tutorial: *addr not defined, why?

Tags: go, wiki

I've been using the Go tutorial [here](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_12) but the final version of the main function returns an error for me:

```
$ go build wiki.go
# command-line-arguments
./wiki.go:97: undefined: addr
```

And it makes sense since this isn't defined in (or even out of) scope. If you take out the entire if-function in the main method, the program builds and works fine, so no idea why it's even included, beyond a little logging functionality.

Does anyone know what the tutorial is trying to get me to do, or how that *addr should have been defined?

Comment: thankfully, that tutorial has been updated since then to not have this confusion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the final code at http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/final.go you'll see that `addr` is defined as a `flag.Bool`. This is a command line flag from the [`flag`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package.

Lines 17 - 19:

```
var (
    addr = flag.Bool("addr", false, "find open address and print to final-port.txt")
)
```

Comment: Thank you. When I wrote this question the full listing was unavailable for whatever reason so I couldn't see this.

Comment: @intermernet: I can't figure out what the if *addr {} block even does.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the full listing here: http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/final.go, addr is declared at the top:

```
var (
    addr = flag.Bool("addr", false, "find open address and print to final-port.txt")
)
```